# How to write variables in a loop while creating netCDF file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, netcdf, python-xarray, enumerate, netcdf4

I have more than 200 time-series variables in a `.csv` file and want to write all variables in a netCDF file. But I don't know why I can't able to do that in a loop. The code with pseudo data are given below:

## Data generate

```py
vars = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
date = pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', end='2021-01-12')
data_dict = {k: np.random.rand(12) for k in vars}
data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict, index=date)
```

## Create netcdf file with dimension

```py
try:
    # just to be safe, make sure dataset is not already open.
    ncfile.close()
except:
    pass

ncfile = Dataset('test.nc', mode='w', format='NETCDF4_CLASSIC')

lat_dim = ncfile.createDimension('lat', 1)    
lon_dim = ncfile.createDimension('lon', 1)    

time_dim = ncfile.createDimension('time', None) 
time = ncfile.createVariable('time', np.float64, ('time',))
time.units = 'Minutes since 2021-01-01 0'
time.long_name = 'time'
    
calendar = 'standard'
time[:] = date2num(
    (pd.to_datetime(data.index)).to_pydatetime(),
    units=time.units,
    calendar=calendar
)
```

## Write netcdf file in a loop

```py
for i, vname in enumerate(var):
    vname = ncfile.createVariable(vname,np.float64,'time')
    vname[:] = data[vname].values
```

I think the problem here is 'vname' which is a string. I tried to convert it into an object but am not able to do that. I am not sure if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `xarray` you could write something like :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

variables = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
date = pd.date_range(start='2021-01-01', end='2021-01-12')
data_dict = {k: np.random.rand(12) for k in variables}
data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict, index=date)
data.index.name = 'time'

ds = data.to_xarray().expand_dims(dim=['lat', 'lon'])
ds.to_netcdf('test.nc', format='NETCDF4')
```

The `to_xarray` method will give you a `xarray.Dataset` with `time` as a coordinate and your four variables. And the `expand_dims` adds the two spatial dimensions.

Tell me if the resulting dataset/netcdf is not exaclty like you want.

Comment: Hi @cyril, yes it create netcdf file with all variables, but still if I want to add more informations like units, description for each variables then how to add this information to each variables

Comment: You can add attributes by writing this just after you created `ds` : `ds['time'].attrs.update({"long_name": "time"})`. For the `calendar` and `units` attributes, xarray automatically writes them when `test.nc` is written. Nevertheless, if you want to set yourself the units, you can write `ds['time'].encoding.update({"units": "Minutes since 2021-01-01"})`. Hope this helps !

Comment: Thank you it helps